# How to display two separate images simultaneously in a user interface using the Matlab APP DESIGNER?

Tags: matlab

I have an user interface which is shown below. There are couple of sections for displaying images in the Image panel. If I click the OPEN button in the Option Panel, an image is displayed on the left side of the Image Panel which is fine. However, problem arises when I click the PROCESS button in the Option Panel. I want the image to be displayed on the right side of the Image Panel. But the image is being displayed on a separate window which I don't want. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgFHv.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qVve.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAceM.jpg

```
% Button pushed function: ProcessButton
        function ProcessButtonPushed(app, event)
            img = imread('Intensity1.jpg');

            % get red, green, blue channels
            redC = img(:,:,1);
            greenC = img(:,:,2);
            blueC = img(:,:,3);
            % mask where red channel is greater than blue channel and green channel greater than blue channel
            mask = redC > blueC & greenC > blueC;
            % overlay mask into original image
            finalimg = bsxfun(@times, img, cast(mask,class(img)));
            f = imshow(finalimg);
            ax = axes('Parent',f);
            plot(ax);
```

The new image is being displayed on a separate window instead of being displayed on the right side of the Image Panel of the user interface. Also, I am getting the following error message:

Error using axes
Axes cannot be a child of Image.

Error in Patient4/ProcessButtonPushed (line 215)
ax = axes('Parent',f);

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the functions `axes` nor `imread` with App Designer.
For example, you create two components named `app.Image` and `app.Image_2`.

You can set the image using the property `ImageSource`.

```
app.Image.ImageSource = 'MyPath\MyImageFileName1.png';
app.Image_2.ImageSource = 'MyPath\MyImageFileName2.png'
```